# SSH with passphrase on three servers

Tags: ssh

I have three servers A,B, and C. I need to do is to run something like:

```
my_self@A:~$ ssh B "ssh C run_a_script_here"
```

This works if I have my ssh keys setup correctly on A,B,C, and I do not use SSH passphrase. But if I run this as a different user who has a SSH passphrase, I got an error:

```
user_has_passphrase@A:~$ ssh B "ssh C run_a_script_here"
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
user_has_passphrase@A: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I checked online and it looks like this is a ssh-agent and/or keychain setup issue, and I have no idea how to set it up as I never used passphrase with my ssh keys.

Thanks,
Philip

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy your private key on host-B and host-C.

Normally, you only add the public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` and host-b and host-c.

Then you can use a proxy jump:

`ssh hostC -o ProxyJump=hostB`

You will be asked only once for your passphrase (on host-A)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this: ssh hostB "ssh hostC -o ProxyJump=hostB" and the message is different this time:
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Host key verification failed.
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: I believe the reason is still with the passphrase.

Comment: @PhilipShangguan Don't add a second `ssh` in the line, just take it, like I described